# Using quantiles to generate a sample of data

Tags: random-generation, quantiles

I have been given quantiles (min, 25%, med, 75%, max) for items of data, along with the size of the data n. From these pieces of information I would like to obtain a random sample of data points.

Apart from the trivial solutions where n ≤ 5, is there any way of doing this?

My attempt at a solution:

After some research I believe my best option is to obtain a distribution from these quantiles and then use inverse transform sampling to randomly sample n items from a given distribution which would give me n random data points that roughly agreed with the quantiles given.

However I am struggling to find digestible reading material on how I can obtain this distribution,  from domain knowledge I suspect this distribution will be highly negatively skewed (Gumbel minimum / minimum extreme distribution)

Here are some related threads:

[Estimating a distribution based on three percentiles](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6022/estimating-a-distribution-based-on-three-percentiles)

[Estimate distribution from 4 quantiles](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/309215/estimate-distribution-from-4-quantiles)

https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/31/parameters-from-percentiles/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The raw quantiles do not uniquely define a distribution. (Unless you have additional information, like that it is normal. In which case the question is whether the quantiles are actually consistent with a normal distribution.)

I would recommend that you draw

- $\frac{n}{4}$ data points that are uniformly distributed in $[q_0, q_{.25}]$
- $\frac{n}{4}$ data points that are uniformly distributed in $[q_{.25}, q_{.5}]$
- $\frac{n}{4}$ data points that are uniformly distributed in $[q_{.5}, q_{.75}]$
- $\frac{n}{4}$ data points that are uniformly distributed in $[q_{.75}, q_1]$

If your $n$ is large and the distances between the quantiles vary much, then this may yield a somewhat "unnatural" histogram:

[image: Histogram]

```
nn <- 1e6
quantiles <- c(0,2,6,12,20)

set.seed(1)

xx <- c(
    runif(nn/4,quantiles[1],quantiles[2]),
    runif(nn/4,quantiles[2],quantiles[3]),
    runif(nn/4,quantiles[3],quantiles[4]),
    runif(nn/4,quantiles[4],quantiles[5]))

hist(xx)
```

If this is a problem for you, then you may want to prespecify a distribution, fit this to the quantiles provided and sample from the distribution, per above. Or try fitting a kernel density estimate to your quantiles and sample from that.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the [Metalog distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalog_distribution) it is possible to get a nice fit to a set of given quantiles. Here is some example code in Python using the [metalogistic](https://pypi.org/project/metalogistic/0.0.7/) package :

```
from metalogistic import MetaLogistic

import sys
eps = sys.float_info.epsilon

# For numeric reasons we cannot use min=0.0 and max=1.0
# Instead we set min=eps, the max=1.0 - eps
quantiles = [eps, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0 - eps]
xs = [0, 2, 6, 12, 20]

metalog = MetaLogistic(cdf_xs=xs, cdf_ps=quantiles)
metalog.print_summary()
```

The output is

```
Fit method used: Linear least squares
    Distribution is valid: True
    Method for determining distribution validity: SmallMReciprocal
    Mean square error: 1.1886423615385787e-28
    a vector: [6.00000000e+00 9.01924897e-17 1.97954724e-15 2.00000000e+01
     1.60000000e+01]
```

To show the distribution simply do

```
metalog.display_plot();
```

[image]

You can sample from the fitted distribution like

```
>>> metalog.rvs(size=(10,))
array([16.82096623, 13.92429775, 19.62488196,  7.96498741,  7.69518981,
    3.90956535,  0.3221118 ,  0.03950283, 12.72069787,  1.54214087])
```